# (Install-Module/Install-Package) cmdlets fail to install a module/package that is not "catalog signed" by the publisher

Tags: powershell

Sometimes I require specific (albiet outdated) versions of a Powershell module/package -

```
Install-Module Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 1.6.0 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force
```

This fails if the package or version specifically is not signed by the publisher even with the `-Force` parameter.

Here's a screencap of the error -
[image: Error Screencap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by simply adding the `-SkipPublisherCheck` parameter in the command -

```
Install-Module Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 1.6.0 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -Force -SkipPublisherCheck
```

More on other tags [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/install-package?view=powershell-7).